How to balance familiarity against prestige when choosing academic references for Phd applications?
I'm busy submitting Phd applications to STEM programs in Europe and am trying to decide on the best combination of references to use. I'm based at a good but not globally renowned university, outside of Europe. I have some professors here who I've been working with for a while and who would agree to act as references.
However I've also had the chance to do some work with an elite university in Europe - at the level of or even higher than the places I'm applying to. I would be able to get some references from the professors there, but the content would be quite generic.
I know it's often said that what matters most in a recommendation is detail and familiarity, but do you think that even a generic stamp of approval from a highly prestigious school could help someone like me coming from the outside? If you had to choose 2 references in my situation, which combination would you go for?

See a similar question here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/96786/reference-letter-personal-vs-prestigious

@ambiguditi Thank you but I don't think that really deals with my situation or the elements I highlighted in the question.

@Mike why not? To me it looks like the same question.

@DavidWhite Because I'm not just looking at 2 colleagues where 1 happens to be more cited, I'm looking at people from totally different universities in different continents (specifically, I'm from a developing country) with the knowledge that 1 of those universities is in the inner circle of the kind of places I'm applying to and the other isn't at all. I also have multiple options from each side and am trying to find the best combination, rather than just 1v1. Maybe doubling down on familiarity is still preferable, but I don't think that question/answer is convincing for my situation.

I also think the situation in this question is different. Familiarity being more important when all your options are from one university doesn't necessarily mean familiarity is more important if your options are a university in a developing country and a much more prestigious university in the country you're applying to.
